# TFLITE can't quantize the input and output of tensorflow model to INT8

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a problem with converting a Tensorflow model to TensorflowLite.
I want to convert the whole model with quantization but when I finalize this step and I visualize the
architecture of the model I find that the input and output are still Float.
Could you help me to solve this problem?

Version Info: tensorflow 2.3.1 / python 3.6

### Data for validation

```py
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    valid_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    classes=classes,
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    )
```

### Architecture of the model

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape= (128,128,3)))

model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))


model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

### After training / convert model to Tflite

```py
def representative_dataset_gen():
    for i in range(20):
        data_x, data_y = validation_generator.next()
        for data_xx in data_x:
            data = tf.reshape(data, shape=[-1, 128, 128, 3])
            yield [data]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen

converter.target_spec.supported_ops =[tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]

converter.inference_input_tpye  = tf.int8

converter.inference_output_tpye = tf.int8

quantiz_model = converter.convert()

open("/content/drive/My Drive/model.tflite", "wb").write(quantiz_model)
```

[model properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILlLF.png)

Comment: Looks like you made a typo, should be ```converter.inference_input_type  = tf.int8

converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8```

Comment: So stupid finally, thank you DAVERIM it is the typing error which poses this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Looks like you made a typo, should be `converter.inference_input_type  = tf.int8`  `converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8` (paraphrased from daverim)

Working code to convert model to Tflite

```
def representative_dataset_gen():
    for i in range(20):
        data_x, data_y = validation_generator.next()
        for data_xx in data_x:
            data = tf.reshape(data, shape=[-1, 128, 128, 3])
            yield [data]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen

converter.target_spec.supported_ops =[tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]

converter.inference_input_type  = tf.int8

converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

quantiz_model = converter.convert()

open("/content/drive/My Drive/model.tflite", "wb").write(quantiz_model)
```